# Ruby date argument out of range

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a time with Time.local which in my code is dynamic. On the first of each month the values I'm passing are Time.local(2009, 9, -1, 0). In PHP this would set the time to the last day of the previous month. In ruby I just get "ArgumentError: argument out of range".

Am I using the wrong method or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `DateTime` class instead of `Time`. (You might have to `require 'date'` and install the `activesupport` gem first.)

It is much more versatile than `Time` and does just what you want with `DateTime.civil(2009,9 - 1,-1,0)`.

Passing -1 for the day gives you the date of the last day of the month from the second argument, so you have to subtract 1 from the current month.

If you are in Rails, you could just do `DateTime.civil(2009,9,1,0) - 1.day` and get what you want with more understandable code.

Comment: But this sets the date to the last day of the current month, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does:

>> DateTime.civil(2009,9,-1)
=> Wed, 30 Sep 2009 00:00:00 +0000

Almost had it!

Comment: Ah yes, made a small mistake there. Will edit my original answer.

Comment: Nice one, that works a treat. I'll vote it up when I get to 15 rep! Thanks

Comment: Also note that with ActiveSupport (included in Rails but can be used standalone) you have #end_of_month which does exactly what you'd expect (for reasonable values of "expect"). See ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Calculations for other useful bits.

Comment: I'd also note that if this is a calculation you're going to be making frequently, Ruby's DateTime class is much, much slower than its Time class.  (Time is mostly written in C, whereas DateTime is pure Ruby and makes heavy use of Rational).  DateTime is more fully featured, however.  (http://third-base.rubyforge.org is an alternative DateTime implementation which claims to be quite a bit faster)